# What is the difference between the "Precision and Recall" and "Completeness and Correctness" performance measures?

Tags: classification, precision-recall, model-evaluation

Can anybody explain to me what the difference is between the "Precision and Recall" and "Completeness and Correctness" performance measures? It seems the calculation of "Precision and Correctness" and "Recall and Completeness" measures are the same as in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)? So why is there two different naming? (I am specifically interested in image processing applications)

Comment: "Precision and Recall" are two common words, but where did you encounter "Completeness and Correctness" words? In the wikipedia link that you have provided, the "correctness" is not explicitly mentioned.

Comment: My bad. You are right, in the link only PR definitions are given. Completeness and correctness definitions are used in various research papers. Sometimes they are even written as Correctness (precision) and Completeness (recall).

Comment: It seems they are just two different naming. What is your question exactly? Do you want to know why completeness and correctness are suitable names for recall and precision, respectively?

Comment: I want to know why there are two different namings? And if they mean exactly the same?

Comment: As I know, Precision and Recall are more common. It makes sense to call precision as correctness and recall as completeness. If it is enough, I can explain why correctness/completeness are sensible names for precision/recall.